# How can I fix cracks in molding on exterior column wraps?

Tags: wood, crack

I am not sure how this happened But I noticed it only today. Can anyone tell me what an I do to fix this?[image]

Answer (score 1):

That's just a pine corner molding. It's 100% decorative and likely fastened with small trim nails. You can usually find a replacement at home improvement stores or lumber yards. Remove, replace, prime, paint. It's about as basic a DIY project as they come.

If you find that the substrate is soft or oddly shaped, consider putting a bead of caulk or construction adhesive inside each edge to help secure it. Wipe away any squeeze-out.

The dark color and shape of the cracks suggests that there was a large knot in that location. Warpage stress or an impact probably cracked it. Try to avoid such knots in a replacement molding.

Comment: Might also be sufficient to slap some glue in, mallet it back into place, sand the joints and repaint.

Comment: Obviously that's been tried before (and failed). You can see the boogering in the photo. It's not a fix, but feel free to put the suggestion in an answer of your own. I'm not sure how it relates to my answer.